# Php preg_match_all does not behave as expected

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Trying to capture all text between tags.

Code:

```
$test = '<test>foo<tests> asdlkfjklas lkflsdakj <test>sdfsd<tests> asdlkaskl <test>235234<tests>';

$match = '/<test>(.*)<tests>/';

preg_match_all($match, $test, $nextLink);
```

Result of print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foo asdlkfjklas lkflsdakj sdfsd asdlkaskl 235234 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => foo asdlkfjklas lkflsdakj sdfsd asdlkaskl 235234 ) )
```

Comment: Use non-greedy quantification `(.*?)`

Comment: Doesn't the result include all the `<test>` and `<tests>` in between everything?

Comment: Use View Source to see what it actually returned, because the browser is hiding the things that look like HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

your regex  syntax is greedy. use folowing:

```
 $match = '/<test>(.*?)<tests>/';
```

Comment: Thanks! But why?? Sorry, not the best with regex!

Comment: @HunterS Read the tutorial, and pay special attention to the part about greediness: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html